# Invalid arguments error when passing macros in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a function like:

```
int kvm_vcpu_ioctl(int vcpu_fd,int type, ...)
{
  int ret;
  void *arg;
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, type);
  arg = va_arg(ap, void *);
  va_end(ap);

  ret = ioctl(vcpu_fd, type, arg);
  if (ret == -1)
    ret = -errno;

  return ret;
}
```

and when I want to call it but pass a macro as the argument like:

```
kvm_vcpu_ioctl(vcpus.fds[vcpu_id],KVM_NITRO_GET_SREGS,sregs);
```

in which defined macro is:

```
#define KVM_NITRO_GET_SREGS             _IOR(KVMIO,  0xE9, struct kvm_sregs)
```

I get this error:

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int kvm_vcpu_ioctl(int, int, ...)

I do not why?

_IOR is :

```
#define _IOR(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_READ,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
```

and _IOC is:

```
#define _IOC(dir,type,nr,size) \
(((dir)  << _IOC_DIRSHIFT) | \
 ((type) << _IOC_TYPESHIFT) | \
 ((nr)   << _IOC_NRSHIFT) | \
 ((size) << _IOC_SIZESHIFT))
```

Comment: And what is `_IOR(...)`?

Comment: @Praetorian `_IOR` is defined in `ioctl.h`.

Comment: Show the declarations of `vcpus.fds[]` and `_IOR()`.  At least one of them isn't `int` or convertible to `int`.

Comment: Is this the first error the compiler gives?

Comment: I'm guessing that `_IOR` uses some shifts and bitwise ORs to combine its arguments, and one of the operands is `sizeof(struct kvm_sregs)`, which returns an `size_t`.

Comment: no it is not the first one but all the errors I get are the same, i.e. passing a macro as the argument

Comment: `_IOR` is a Linux macro to construct ioctl numbers. It should produce an `int` unless its given unusual arguments, which doesn't look like the case here.

Comment: Are you sure that `vcpus.fds[vcpu_id]` is an `int`?

Comment: @user2092506: You need to learn how to build a minimal example that other users can compile to help debug your errors. For example, in this case, I imagine you see the same issues with [this code](https://gist.github.com/sharth/2f54458e112eba24d12a).

Comment: @user2092506: Additionally, I imagine that gcc pushed out more lines of output than the __one line__ that you have shown us. Could you show __all__ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `KVM_NITRO_GET_SREGS` "calls" `_IOR` with a third argument of `struct kvm_sregs`. From the definition of `_IOR`, it would appear that perhaps a `sizeof(struct kvm_sregs)` might be more appropriate. Or perhaps you have arguments out of order, since it appears the first argument to `_IOR` should possibly be a `type`, but I'm not sure what `KVMIO` expands to...

Look for other locations where `_IOR` is used in other drivers, and mimic those.

Comment: As seen in the [linux kernel sources](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.15/include/uapi/linux/usbdevice_fs.h#L160), the third argument of `_IOR` should be a type. The macro will place `sizeof()` around it.

Comment: @sharth Ok, that does seem to be the case. It seems a bit odd that a `size` argument to a macro shouldn't actually be a size, but should be a type instead. Ah well, I'm sure it's not the only strange thing in the kernel source...